# Angle between two lines using two gradients where one is infinite

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, angle

I am trying to find the angle between two lines;
I found the gradient of the first line which was 0.9.
I tried to find the gradient of the second line but i got n/0, which is obviously infinite.

I was wondering, what I should do in this situation?

Many thanks,

Mighty Garlic

Comment: What is "n"? I'd say $0/n=0$, not infinity... Can you add some context, perhaps the equations of the lines?

Comment: sorry made a mistake when n/0 where n >0

Comment: No problem but it would still help if you added some details such as the equations of the lines in question.

Comment: 1) Why don't you say plainly that one of your lines is an horizontal line ? 2) you speak about an infinite gradient, as if it was a number (are you thinking about a slope ?) whereas a gradient is a **vector**: you will have no problem is you work with vectors. In a concrete way, with an example, the gradient of $7x-9y+3=0$ is vector $(7,-9)$ which is orthogonal to this line.

Comment: Cheers man, I was getting really confused. I forgot the difference between slope and gradient, vectors solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\pm\infty=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\tan\pm\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varepsilon\right)$.

Comment: I am afraid you indication is of no help for somebody that visibly has difficulties (who speaks of a gradient instead of a slope etc...)

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't know for OP, but not everybody in here is a native english speaker. There can be discrepancies between math level and vocabulary known for english's math. For instance http://www.wordreference.com/fren/pente gives me either slope or gradient. As well as this math page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope

Comment: @zwim I appreciate your thorough remarks.